# Compare 3 user variables (row count) and raise an error if they didn't match

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm using script task in SSIS package.

I'd like to compare 3 user variables (row count between 3 tables) and raise an error if they are not equal. Otherwise it's is a success.

I'm new in C# developpment.

I need your help.

Thanks

here is my code  :

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            //MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::RowCtn_src1"].Value.ToString());
            //MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::RowCtn_src2"].Value.ToString());
            //MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::RowCtn_src3"].Value.ToString());
            Dts.Variables["User::RowCtn_src1"].Value = "";
            Dts.Variables["User::RowCtn_src2"].Value = "";
            Dts.Variables["User::RowCtn_src3"].Value = "";
            Dts.Variables["User::Err"].Value = "";
            
            if ("User::RowCtn_src1" == "User::RowCtn_src2" == "User::RowCtn_src3")     //As you an see there is error in the code

                //this what I want : 
                //if it's true then success otherwise raise un error'
                //How can I do it?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

- The row count variables should be defined as a number data type like int.
- The variables should be set in some prior task, like a data flow.
- The comparison between the 3 can be done by comparing two pairs, then all 3 must match.

You might do it like this:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        int src1 = (int)Dts.Variables["User::RowCtn_src1"].Value;
        int src2 = (int)Dts.Variables["User::RowCtn_src2"].Value;
        int src3 = (int)Dts.Variables["User::RowCtn_src3"].Value;

        if (src1 != src2 || src2 != src3)
        {
            var msg = $"Counts do not match.  src1= {src1}; src2= {src2}; src3= {src3};";
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Row Count Check", msg, "", 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this in a SQL task if you are measuring table counts.

Set the result into a variable and then use the control flow path to flow 0 into your error handler.

```
select iif(ct1=ct2,iif(ct2=ct3,1,0),0) doCountsMatch
from (select count(*) ct1 from table1) a
cross apply (select count(*) ct2 from table2) b
cross apply (select count(*) ct3 from table3) c
```

This will also work and easier to add more table counts:

```
select iif(Min(ct)=Max(ct),1,0) doCountsMatch
from (select count(*) ct from table1 
union all select count(*) ct2 from table2
union all select count(*) ct3 from table3) cts
```